# Deserialize JSON using JSON.net in Wp7 application

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, json.net, deserialization

I have this JSON format:

```
string jsonFormat = @"{ 
""Applications"": {
        ""data"": {
            ""Application named one"": [
                {
                    ""index"" : ""1"",
                    ""name"" : ""One"",
                    ""active"" : ""1"",
                    ""excluded"" : ""false""
                }
            ],
            ""Application named two"": [
                {
                    ""index"" : ""2"",
                    ""forum"" : ""yes"",
                }
            ]
        } 
    } 
}";
```

How exactly I can acces `data` childrens ? I need to retreive `Application named one` and `Application named two` - for each also the attributes with their values - the attributes are different from Application to Application.

Untill now I have:

```
        JObject resultt= JObject.Parse(jsonFormat);
        // get JSON result objects into a list
        IList<JToken> results = resultt["Applications"]["data"].Children().ToList();
```

I looked over JSON.net documentation and could not find a solution for this...

Any help will be very usefull. Thank you.

Comment: I just can not getting work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonFormat);
int index = jObject
    .Value<JObject>("Applications")
    .Value<JObject>("data")
    .Value<JArray>("Application named one")
    .First
    .Value<int>("index");
```

Basically the idea is to use the `Value` method with the type you are expecting to retrieve a specific json element (JObject, JArray, ...) or parse a .NET value (int, string, bool, ...).

Comment: isn't exactly what I wanted - and I'm saying this because I do not know "Application named one" name but I figured out a solution for this. I'll post the solution tomorrow or the day after tomorrow. Thanks.